# Print out variable from another class?

Tags: java, sockets

this class `Time`:

```
public class Time {

  int secondPassed = 0;
  Timer mytime = new Timer()

  TimerTask mytask = new TimerTask() {
    public void run()  {
      secondPassed++;

      if(secondPassed == 3) {
        secondPassed = 0;

         Udp callUdp = new Udp();
         String trnsferRP = callUdp.trnsfrRPckt();
         System.out.println(trnsferRP + "exp");
         System.out.println("Its 10");
      }
       else {
         System.out.println("Second : " + secondPassed);
      }
    }
  };

  public void start(){
    mytime.scheduleAtFixedRate(mytask, 1000,1000);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Time starter = new Time();
    starter.start();
  }
}
```

this is class `UDP`:

```
public class Udp {

  public DatagramPacket receivePacket;
  public String result;

  public void socketp() throws Exception {
    DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(10076);
    InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.100.10");
    byte[] sendData = new byte[9];
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[9];
    String sentence = "VDV2bE1";
    sendData = sentence.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 10076);
    clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
    this.receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
    clientSocket.close();
    this.result = new String(receivePacket.getData());
    return;
  }

  public String trnsfrRPckt(){
    return this.result;
  }
}
```

so I'm trying to call a variable from `class Udp` to `class Time`, by that I'm want to print the packet received. Currently my result is:

```
second : 1
second : 2
nullexp
its 10
```

why null came out? should be a packet data + "exp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never called

```
callUdp.socketp();
```

Which is the only function that write to result variable. So your result is null until you have a call to socketp().

Comment: thanks, i dont know try and catch method before so even i put it in its said error..thanks for helping

Comment: Your try and catch blocks are fine. and your program is fine too. Try and catch block is used for handling exceptions. calling trnsfrRPckt() before  socketp doesn't throw an exception since trnsfrRPckt return null. You simply have an human error.. :)

Comment: ooo ok got it,so it works like that.. sorry new to programming,pardon me for the error